# An error occurred while creating datasets: (table_name) Table could not be found for mixpanel data in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, apache-superset, mixpanel

new to superset here. I'm connecting mixpanel data (stored in redshift) to superset, but I do not see tables available when I 'add dataset' in superset. Specifically, I want to connect to `mp_master_event`,  and I wonder if the reason it does not show is because it's stored under "External Tables?"

[image]

[image]

When I type `mp_master_event` in the 'table' field, I get this error: `An error occurred while creating datasets: (table_name) Table [mp_master_event] could not be found, please double check your database connection, schema, and table name`. The database connection is fine and the schema 'mixpanel' I've chosen is right.

Any ideas what I should do?